# Should there be a tag for timescale or timescaledb?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

Actually there is a tag for [time-series-database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series-database), but as the OP in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226574/how-to-partition-a-table-without-time-data) has suggested, may be there should be a tag for [timescale](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timescale) or [timescaledb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timescaledb).

A search for [timescale](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=timescale) returns 12 results, I'm not sure if that is enough to add a new tag.

And it seems that [TimescaleDB 1.0](https://blog.timescale.com/announcing-1-0-enterprise-ready-time-series-database-sql-open-source-400b4342dfa0) is enterprise ready since Sep 2018.

Comment: I created a tab before for it, my guess is someone deleted it? There should def be a tag for timescaledb

Comment: Not exactly on-topic, but I've recently seen [tag:timescaledb] being used to tag questions about time-series databases in general even when "timescaledb" wasn't in the question.

Comment: @mustaccio I suppose someone has created it after this question has been posted. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226574/how-to-partition-a-table-without-time-data#comment446427_226574

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

All databases open-source and proprietary with more than one question should have their own tag and tag-wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Having asked some a question about it recently, I say yes but I don't have the required rep.

Answer (score 2):

I vote Yes, there should probably be one for `citus` too